# Enviar o id/pk da views para form.ModelForm

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou com uma duvida de como passar o id/pk da view para o form:

Criei um Precadastro onde adiciono nome e cpf etc..., e depois que executo uma consulta, criei um botão para criar um cadastro:

Novo Cadastro
                                
Models:

```
class PreCadastro(models.Model):
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    nome = models.CharField('Pessoa', max_length=100)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(choices=CARGO, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    setor = models.CharField(choices=SETOR, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Nome:{self.nome}, CPF:{self.cpf}'

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pertence_nome = models.OneToOneField(PreCadastro, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Pessoa')
    tipoformacao = models.CharField(choices=ESPECIALIDADE, max_length=100)
    datadenascimento = models.DateField()
    nomesocial = models.CharField('Nome Social', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    sexo = models.CharField(choices=SEXO, max_length=9)    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Pessoa'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pessoas'
        permissions = [
            ('pesquisa_pessoa', 'Permit Pesquisar o Colaborador'),
            ('editar_pessoa', 'Permit Editar as Informações de um Colaborador')
        ]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pessoa-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Nome: {self.pertence_nome}, Datanascimento: {self.datadenascimento}'
```

url.py:
path('cadastrarpessoa/int:pk/', PessoaCreate.as_view(), name='cadastrarpessoa'),

E estou tentando enviar o id/pk de uma consulta na urls:http://127.0.0.1:8080/pessoas/cadastrarpessoa/1062/ em uma variável para meu form.

Veiew:

```
class PessoaCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CadastrarPessoaForm
    template_name = 'pessoas/pessoa_form.html'
    success_url = 'sucesso'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        variavelpk = PreCadastro.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form = self.get_form(variavelpk)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

forms:

```
class CadastrarPessoaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, variavelpk=1062, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CadastrarPessoaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pertence_nome'].initial = PreCadastro.objects.get(pk=variavelpk)

    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa

        fields = [
                  'pertence_nome',
                  'tipoformacao',
                  'nomesocial',
                  'datadenascimento',
                  'sexo',                  
                  ]
        widgets = {
            'pertence_nome': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase', 'readonly': 'True'}),
            'tipoformacao': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control', 'aria-label': 'example', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'nomesocial': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'datadenascimento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control datepicker'}),
            'sexo': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control', 'aria-label': 'example', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),            
        }
```

Quanto tento acessar o pk que envio para o form desta forma:

```
 def __init__(self, variavelpk, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CadastrarPessoaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pertence_nome'].initial = PreCadastro.objects.get(pk=variavelpk)
```

Da o seguinte erro:
**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variavelpk'

mas quando adiciono um numero de id assim:

```
def __init__(self, variavelpk=1062, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CadastrarPessoaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pertence_nome'].initial = PreCadastro.objects.get(pk=variavelpk)
```

Funciona ou seja não estou conseguindo acessar o id na variável quando vem da view.

Se possível me ajudem a entender como enviar o id/pk da view para o form.
Pois preciso que no momento de criar um novo cadastro o selec do OnToOne venha com a informação da pessoas referente ao id.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de de um tempo entendi melhor o problema e vou deixar aqui para a posteridade a solução que encontrei para este problema,
depois de juntar bastante informação consegui fazer isso:

na views consegui armazenar o id paraso pela listview para uma variavel 'pk':

#views

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('precadastro_id')
    kwargs = super(PessoaCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'pertence': pk})
    return kwargs
```

e aqui passar para o forme filtrar o seletec atraves da variavel 'pk' que vem da view:

#forms

```
def __init__(self, pertence, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(CadastrarPessoaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    fil = PreCadastro.objects.get(pk=pertence)
    self.fields['pertence_nome'].initial = fil
```